# how to build copy constructor to CharNode

Tags: java

This is my CharNode class

```
public class CharNode
  {
    private char _data;
    private int _value;
    private CharNode _next;
    public CharNode(char c, int val, CharNode n) 
        {
         _data = c;
         _value = val;
         _next = n;
        }

   public CharNode getNext( ) 
      { return _next; }
   public void setNext(CharNode node) 
      { _next = node; }
   public int getValue() 
      { return _value; }
   public void setValue(int v) 
      { _value = v; }
   public char getData()
      { return _data; }
   public void setData(char c) 
      { _data = c; }
}
```

I use this class StringList that use the CharNode

```
private CharNode _head;

//Stringlist have constractor 


public StringList ()
       _head= null;

//and 

StringList (charNode node)
    _head = node;
```

I need to build copy constractor, how do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Or you just want from us to receive full ready code of the homework decision?

Comment: If you know what a copy constructor is, I don't see what difficulty you could be having.  What have you tried? What are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2):

A copy constructor takes a reference to the object that you need to be copied and initialised itself with the attribuet values of the object passed in:

```
public CharNode(CharNode node) {

     _data = node._data;
     _value = node._value;
     _next = node._next;
}
```

Copying the reference to the next object in the chain might not be what you need
as that results in 2 nodes pointing to the same next node.

Also, you should check that the node passed in is not `null` and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if it is `null`.

Comment: this copy constractor need to be like that

public StringList (StringList other)

Comment: like i say the copy constractor cant use build in class of java,i need to build my on copy constractor.

the sing of the constractor is :**public StringList (StringList other)**

i send a new String of StringList,and copy is Value's


pls help me

best regards

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would implement `clone()` method from `Object` class but since you are new to Java it would be easy if you would just implement a method

```
public MyObject cloneMyObject(MyObject myObject) {
    MyObject cloneMyObject = new MyObject();
    cloneMyObject.field1 = myObject.field1; //shallow clone
    cloneMyObject.field1 = myObject.field1.cloneThisObject(); //deep clone
    //and so on;
    return cloneMyObject;        
}
```

Also see the [Prototype pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern).

Comment: i cant use java buils obj,i need to make it by me only

the copy constrator get other StringList copy the value this is the sing of the constractor


this is LINKNODE 

public StringList (StringList other)

Comment: Then what you want isn't typically called a copy constructor.  It is a marshaller (to String) and an unmarshaller (from String).  Copy constructors generally make duplicate copies of the same object, by copying the internal fields of the source object into the newly constructed copy.

Comment: like i say the copy constractor cant use build in class of java,i need to build my on copy constractor.

the sing of the constractor is :**public StringList (StringList other)**

i send a new String of StringList,and copy is Value's


pls help me

best regards